# Can I make Perl ithreads in Windows run concurrently?

Tags: perl, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Perl script that I'm attempting to set up using Perl Threads (use threads).  When I run simple tests everything works, but when I do my actual script (which has the threads running multiple SQL*Plus sessions), each SQL*Plus session runs in order (i.e., thread 1's sqlplus runs steps 1-5, then thread 2's sqlplus runs steps 6-11, etc.).

I thought I understood that threads would do concurrent processing, but something's amiss.  Any ideas, or should I be doing some other Perl magic?

Comment: I, and would guess others, are curious to hear some follow-up on this question.  Did you find a solution?  Were the answers here helpful?

Comment: What Frosty said... What was the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possible explanations:

1. Are you running this script on a multi-core processor or multi-processor machine?  If you only have one CPU only one thread can use it at any time.
2. Are there transactions or locks involved with steps 1-6 that would prevent it from being done concurrently?
3. Are you certain you are using multiple connections to the database and not sharing a single one between threads?

Comment: There was only one DB connection happening, which wasn't what I expected.  Thanks for the idea (never thought to check that), now I have work to do...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have no way of guaranteeing in which order threads will execute. So the behavior (if not what you expect) is not really wrong.

I suspect you have some kind of synchronization going on here. Possibly SQL*Plus only let's itself be called once? Some programs do that...

Other possiblilties:

- thread creation and process creation (you *are* creating subprocesses for SQL*Plus, aren't you?) take longer than running the thread, so thread 1 is finished before thread 2 even starts
- You are using transactions in your SQL scripts that force synchronization of database updates.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database settings. You may find that it is set up in a conservative manner. That would cause even minor reads to block all access to that information.

You may also need to call `threads::yield`.